# getJson didnt work no console error but no response in the chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, getjson

```
function loadNewsList(pageindex){
    var searchString = document.getElementById("searchBox");
    $('#ulnews').append("<li>into the function</li>");

    var sendData = {
        pageIndex: pageindex,
        searchstring: searchString.value
    };

    $.getJSON("handleListDisplay.php", sendData, function(jsonData) {
        $('#ulnews').append("<li>gets in to getjson</li>");         
        $.each(jsonData.news, function(index, newsdata){
            var time = timeConverter(newsdata["time"]);
            var data = newsdata["content"];
            var content = data.substr(0,50);    
            $('#ulnews').append("<li>get to .each function</li>");
            $('#ulnews').append("<li><a href='displayNewsEntry.php?newsId=" + newsdata["id"] + "' class='newsHeadline'>" + newsdata["headline"] + "</a><h5>" + time + "</h5><h4>" + content + "...</h4></li>");
        });

        $('#ulnews').append("<li>outside of .each function</li>");      
    });
    $('#ulnews').append("<li>outside of getJSON</li>"); 
}
```

the append are for my debugging use and the browser only show into the function and outside of getJSON
and my php file look sth like this

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('server', 'myusername', 'mypassword') or die ('Failed to Connect '.mysqli_error($conn));
    mysqli_select_db($conn,'dbname') or die ('Failed to Access DB'.mysqli_error($conn));

    $searchString = $_GET["searchstring"];

    if ($searchString.length == 0) 
    {
        $query = "select count(*) from news";
    }
    else 
    {
        $query = "select count(*) from news where headline like '%".$searchString."%'";
    }

    $json = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ('Failed to query '.mysqli_error($conn));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);   
    $row_count = $row[0];
    $json[] = array('NoOfRecords' => $row_count);

    $pagenum = 5 * ($_GET["pageIndex"]);

    if ($searchString.length == 0)
    {
        $query = "select * from news order by time desc, headline asc limit 5 offset ".$pagenum;
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "select * from news where headline like '%".$searchString."%' order by time desc, headline asc limit 5 offset ".$pagenum;
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ('Failed to query '.mysqli_error($conn));

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $json[] = array('id'=>$row2['newsID'], 'headline'=>$row2['headline'], 'content' => $row2['content'], 'time' =>$row2['time']);
    }

    print json_encode(array('news'=>$json));    
?>
```

my webpage is fine just come out with into the function and outside of .each function in the ul id=ulnews but the development tools network tab when click the handleListDisplay.php there is a window on the left tht have headers preview response and timing and in that response it is blank

my question is i cant seem to find any error but

```
$('#ulnews').append("<li><a href='displayNewsEntry.php?newsId=" + newsdata["id"] + "' class='newsHeadline'>" + newsdata["headline"] + "</a><h5>" + time + "</h5><h4>" + content + "...</h4></li>");
```

does not output anything in the `<ul id="ulnews">...</ul>`

I cant seem to find the problem its probably obvious plz forgive me as a noob

Comment: Where do you call your `loadNewsList()` function?

Comment: well there is a response tab below the network tab and when clicked the php file i got a blank page

Comment: when the page load @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: but do you get this output `"<li>gets in to getjson</li>"`? btw. you should use `console.log()` for debugging

Comment: no i didnt 
i m sorry i didnt know how to use console.log()

Comment: but your request is being sent and you get HTTP-Code 200?

Comment: yes all 200 before i tried include("index.html") and the response is the webpage but slightly different like without css

Comment: but you just said, your request is empty? and now its a webpage?

Comment: in case of CORS-requests you may get empty result in the browser, since it violates the policy. Make sure you send your request to the same domain where your page is. If not, you need to add the CORS-Header on the server side

Comment: wait i thk my comment is not accurate enough my webpage is fine just come out with into the function and outside of .each function in the ul id=ulnews but the development tools network tab when click the handleListDisplay.php there is a window on the left tht have headers preview response and timing and in that response it is blank

Comment: pls clarify in your question, what is actually happening, its not easy to follow your comments